# Explain this XSS string, it uses perl

Tags: php, javascript, xss, sanitization

I am trying to test one of my php sanitization classes against a few xss scripts available on
http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

So one of the scripts in there has perl in it, is this some kind of a perl statement?? And would this execute directly on the server, since perl is a server scripting language.

```
perl -e 'print "<IMG SRC=java\0script:alert(\"XSS\")>";' > out
```

Is the script that I am trying to work with. I have not tested it yet though, but I want to understand before I use it.

Comment: They are just using perl here to generate a string containing an ASCII 0 character. You could use any language you know to generate such a string.

Comment: Why are you creating your own sanitation code when there are plenty of libraries out there that do ti already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Perl isn't the attack, it just demonstrates how to generate the attack, since you can't see it in a plain string.

The point is that there is a null character (represented in Perl as `\0`) in the data.

Comment: `"javas\0cript"` is not the same as `"javascript"`, so it will get through a filter looking for `"javascript"` but some browsers will still execute it.

Answer (score 2):

The `\0` is a string termination character in the laguage C. Since perl is built on top of C, in the old days you could inject this "poisonous null byte" to make the C part read the line 
`<IMG SRC=java` instead of the whole string, and thus maybe allow the whole thing through even though you were trying to strip stuff like `SRC=javascript:`

Mostly this doesn't work anymore because the higher level languages has gotten pretty good at defeating attacks like this by stripping out stray control chars like `\0` before sending the strings on to the lower level routines.

You can read more on the poison nullbyte here: http://insecure.org/news/P55-07.txt or here: http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte